# Is there a way for a for loop to not go back to the code on top if the next if statement is true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
a = 0
b = 0

for x in range (100):
    a = a + 1
    if a == 10:
        b = b + 1

print(a)
print(b)
```

The outcome

```
99
1
```

What I want

```
10
90
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should do the trick:

```
a = 0
b = 0
for x in range (100):

    if a < 10:
        a = a + 1
    else:
        b = b + 1
```

But to simplify further, you can use python's assignment operator, `a += 1` syntax, which increments the value of `a` by 1:

```
a = 0
b = 0
for x in range (100):

    if a < 10:
        a += 1
    else:
        b += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional check.

```
a = 0
b = 0

for x in range (100):
    if (a % 10 != 0 or a==0):
        a = a + 1
    else:
        b = b + 1

print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
a, b = 0, 0
for x in range(100):
    add = a % 10 != 0 or a == 0
    a += add
    b += not add
```

This uses the fact that a bool is an int although I don’t advise it as it’s not too readable